# Crash occurring occasionally when shutting down TextToSpeech object in JobService

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler, google-text-to-speech

My implementation of TTS (text to speech) using JobService is as follows:

```
package services;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.job.JobParameters;
import android.app.job.JobService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;

import utilities.PhoneUtils;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public class TTSJobScheduledService extends JobService {

private static TextToSpeech voice =null;

public static TextToSpeech getVoice() {
    return voice;
}

@Override
public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
    startTTSEngine();
    PhoneUtils.scheduleTTSJob(getApplicationContext()); // reschedule the job
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
    clearTtsEngine();
    return true;
}

private void startTTSEngine()
{
    try{
        voice = new TextToSpeech(TTSJobScheduledService.this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(final int status) {

            }
        });
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static void clearTtsEngine()
{
    if(voice!=null)
    {
        voice.stop();
        voice.shutdown();
        voice = null;
    }
}
}
```

On some HUAWEI devices, it is causing a crash as follows:

```
Caused by java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech$Connection@2b329ed
   at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1659)
   at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1854)
   at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:703)
   at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech$Connection.disconnect(TextToSpeech.java:2287)
   at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech$1.run(TextToSpeech.java:855)
   at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech$1.run(TextToSpeech.java:851)
   at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech$Connection.runAction(TextToSpeech.java:2307)
   at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.runAction(TextToSpeech.java:752)
   at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.runActionNoReconnect(TextToSpeech.java:738)
   at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.shutdown(TextToSpeech.java:850)
   at services.TTSJobScheduledService.clearTtsEngine(Unknown Source:11)
   at services.TTSJobScheduledService.onStopJob(Unknown Source)
   at android.app.job.JobService$1.onStopJob(JobService.java:76)
   at android.app.job.JobServiceEngine$JobHandler.handleMessage(JobServiceEngine.java:117)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:109)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7377)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:469)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:963)
```

I understand that it is trying to clear a service which might already have been cleared. But, I am not sure how to correctly implement the *clearTTSEngine* method in this case. Can somebody let me know what could be wrong and how to fix it?